# Gauss divergence theorem: verification in first octant

Tags: calculus

Please help me. I have checked several times, and resulted wrong in verification of this particular problem. Please solve for me.

Verify Gauss divergence theorem for $F = (3xz)i + (y + zx)j + (xyz + z)k,$ where $'V'$ is the volume bounded by the coordinate planes and the plane $2x + 3y + 6z = 12$ in the first octant.

work done:  I have taken the limits for integrating: for x: 0 to 6, for y: 0 to (12-2x)/3 and z: 0 to (12-2x-3y)/6 and then I got the value after integration is 37.6. when I verified the same by integral f.n with respect to s, I got 43.6. which is unmatched to my previous answer. Please let me know, where I am wrong?

-manmohan

Comment: Show some working out then it is easy to  see where you may or may not gone wrong.

Comment: @chinny84! please verify. I am unable to type here my math equation, as I am new to this.

Comment: Chinny84! I have taken the limits for integrating: for x: 0 to 6, for y: 0 to (12-2x)/3 and z: 0 to (12-2x-3y)/6 and then I got the value after integration is 37.6. when I verified the same by integral f.n.ds, I got 43.6. which is unmatched to my previous answer. Please let me know, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell where you went wrong: perhaps you forgot to integrate along *all* the surface that bounds your volume $V$?

Namely, the divergence theorem says

$$
\int_S \langle F, dS\rangle = \int_V \mathrm{div}Fdxdydz , \
$$

where $S = \partial V = S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + S_4$, where $S_1$ is your plane $2x + 3y + 6z = 12$ *and* $S_2, S_3, S_4$ the (portions of the) coordinates planes that help $S_1$ bound $V$. That is, the integral on the left hand side is actually composed of *four* integrals:

$$
\int_S \langle F, dS\rangle = \int_{S_1} \langle F, dS \rangle + \dots + \int_{S_4} \langle F, dS \rangle \ .
$$

**EDIT.** Ok, so a few more computations. On the one hand,

$$
\int_{S_1}\langle F, dS \rangle = \int_{D_1} \langle F\circ\varphi, \varphi_x \times \varphi_y\rangle dxdy \ ,
$$

where $D_1 = \left\{ 0\leq x \leq 6, 0 \leq y \leq \frac{12 -2x}{3}\right\}$ and $\varphi (x,y) = (x,y, (12 -2x-3y )/6)$. Hence our integral is:

$$
\int_0^6\int_0^{(12 -2x)/3} \left( 3x\frac{12-2x-3y}{6}, y + \frac{12-2x-3y}{6}x, (xy+1)\frac{12-2x-3y}{6}    \right)
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 \\
1/2  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}dydx \ .
$$

That is,

$$
\int_0^6\int_0^{(12 -2x)/3} \left(\frac{y}{2} + \frac{12 -2x -3y}{4}x + \frac{12-2x-3y}{6} \right)dydx \ .
$$

If $S_2$ is the face $y=0$ of $V$, then

$$
\int_{S_2}\langle F, dS \rangle = \int_{D_2}\left( 3xz, zx , z\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
-1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} dzdx = \int_0^6\int_0^{(12-x)/3}(-zx)dzdx \ .
$$

And you should try to write down now $\int_{S_3}$ and $\int_{S_4}$ -if you haven't done yet.

On the other hand,

$$
\int_V \mathrm{div}F dxdydz = \int_0^6\int_0^{(12-2x)/3}\int_0^{(12-2x-3y)/6} (3z + 2 + xy)dzdydx \ .
$$

So, if you understand those previous integrals and are able to write down those correspondint to the triangles $S_3$ and $S_4$, this would be enough. The rest of the computations are quite long and boring.

Comment: a.r.! I am extremely so sorry for asking you to solve the entire problem. Still I am not recognized, where I did mistake? Please solve and check. Please

Comment: Did you compute the four integrals I'm talking about?

Comment: A.r.! Thank you for your response. I did and may be I am wrong in calculation part. Moreover, I am unable to type here, whatever I did. Please solve, so that I will learn from you. I am trying this problem from last few days and I am very dispointed. Please solve. I think, I may get solution by you.

Comment: a.r! I understand the complete computation part. I need little help.when you find $S_1$, there is a column matrix (1/3, 1/2, 1). How you got this column matrix? please explain. Then everything is ok for me. I want to know the computation part of column matrix.

Comment: This column vector is $\varphi_x \times \varphi_y$.

Comment: a.r! please explain this column vector in more detailed... please

Comment: $\varphi_x, \varphi_y$ are the partial derivatives of $\varphi$ and $\varphi_x \times \varphi_y$ their cross product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_product .